# SWF not reading xml outside of adobe flash

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I managed to create a ticker that pulls data from xml and display them on a moving textfield.
the xml is on an online server.

whenever i run the project from adobe flash (ctrl + enter) 
the flash loads correctly, 
however, when i publish it, the xml does not load and no text is shown in the swf file.

any possible way to have the xml load using the swf file only?

thanks

Comment: Sounds like cross domain issue. Is the XML on the same server (domain) as the SWF?

Comment: I need to have the swf locally , but i have control over the XML, is there anyway to debug this to make sure its a cross domain issue ? 
i'm generating the xml with PHP on an online server

Comment: Sounds like the server needs a crossdomain.xml and/or the flashplayer may need you to add that URL in settings as a trusted location. Also there is a SWF setting that allows either Local access to files, or network access to files, you might need to change which one is selected.

Comment: Are you deploying your SWF to a Web server or publishing a local projector? Explain "need to have the swf locally".

Comment: I'll try allowing all domains from the header of the PHP, the data are not sensitive or private.

and yes, i need the swf on a local computer connected to large screen without any web integration. just swf file :/ is that possible ?

Comment: C.Parcell, can you guide me to find those settings?
also i added header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); to my PHP file.. but that didn't help...
i dont think its a cross domain issue, when i click ctrl+enter in adobe flash, it works normally

Comment: I noticed that if i open it in web , open up the console, im getting the error 404 not found of mydomain.com/crossdomain.xml...


my main domain was mydomain.com/index.php , why did it change to crossdomain.xml ? 

any advise on how to solve that and prevent the url from changing ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I assume we are talking about a kiosk here. You will need to trust the domain where the XML is located.

From the client machine access this site. http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

Add your domain into the area at the bottom and select **Always allow**

That should be enough, but if you need to go further you will need a **crossdomain.xml** on the web server. It should look like this (generally).

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply.

This fixed the problem in my browser, however, it still does not load in adobe flash player :/ i did both crossdomain.xml and the always allow setting. 
chrome no longer returns an error and it loads correctly. but is it fixable in adobe flash player without browser ?

Comment: Are we talking about a published projector or within the Flash IDE?

Comment: when i run it in adobe flash pro (the one its created with) it pull the xml normally. 
when i click publish to extract the swf, it does not pull the data from the xml. its really weird i don't understand the problem, (I'm running it with adobe flash player)

Comment: Use the Settings Manager link shown above. Just as you added your domain now you must a folder from your hardrive that you are testing SWF files from (**Edit Locations**). May be annoying but this is done to stop some random SWF on any folder just connecting to the net. If you set a "Testing" folder, only the SWFs in there will connect to the net.

Comment: VC.One is correct. The problem is that the Flash Player within the Flash IDE is different and separate from the one you have installed in your browser(s). The IDE version has a lot less restrictions because only you the developer would ever be using it. The browser and standalone players are widely distributed and thus need to be more restrictive by default.

Comment: this is frustrating :( it didn't work either.
i tried adding the files, no luck. turned off firewalls, added trusted files, added crossdomain xml . nothing :( any other suggestions ? thank you so much for your comments

Comment: Just to cover the trusted part...Try adding C:\ as a trusted site. I am assuming you are on Windows and that your file is running from that drive. If it is another drive then add it instead.

Comment: For complete coverage, you may want to look at your systems internet settings. Control Panel > Internet Options > Advanced > Security (heading) and check (ON) Allow active content to run in files on My Computer